# Starting a Seam 3 project using Maven from scratch

Tags: maven, jboss, glassfish, seam, seam3

I want to start writing a Seam 3 project from scratch using Maven and configure it to be deployable to both of Glassfish 3.1 and JBoss 6 or 7.

Any references or tutorials explaining how my `pom.xml` file should look like if I don't want to use something like Seam Forge to generate it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use an Archtype to get started and then customize it to your specific needs. The Weld Achetypes are good starting points since if Weld is working it is just a matter of adding the Seam 3 module dependencies and IIRC there are also Glassfish targets preconfigugred in the Archetype POMs.

You can find a few Archtypes [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.weld.archetypes)

Mind that you will have to modify the dependency versions in the POM since they use old versions but everything else should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think [www.seamframework.org](http://www.seamframework.org/Seam3) is a great place to start.

You can also look at the source code of the Seam 3 plugins to get a grip on how the pom file looks like.